# Setting the RGB levels of pixels (Python, Jython)

Tags: python, jython

```
   For each pixel in pic:
    r= random()      
    if r < 0.25:       
    set the red level to randrange(0,256), 
    set the green level to randrange(0,256) 
    set the blue level to randrange(0,256)
```

The rest of the unseen code is correct, I just can't figure out how to phrase this function well enough for it to work.

Comment: What is the format of `pixel`?

Comment: You could start by indenting it correctly. A mixture of tabs and spaces isn't a good idea...

Comment: for px in getPixels(pic)

Comment: you should post your answer as a question and mark it the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about the rest of your code, but it would be something like this:

```
import random

for pixel in pic.get_pixels(): # Replace with appropiate way of getting the pixels
    if random.random() < 0.25:
        pixel.red = random.randint(256)
        pixel.green = random.randint(256)
        pixel.blue = random.randint(256)
```

Again, I don't know how you get a list of the pixels, or how you set the RGB values for each one, but the result would be something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using PIL?

If so one option is to do something like this

```
your_image = Image.new("RGB", (512, 512), "white")
for x in xrange(your_image.size[0]):
    for y in xrange(your_image.size[1]):
        your_image.putpixel((x,y),(random.randint(256), random.randint(256), random.randint(256))
```

Oh... I see you got it.  Well I'll post this anyways.